# writing two lists to separate csv columns

Tags: python, json, export-to-csv

I am attempting to parse a json into a csv, into separate columns but it keeps getting combined into one.

People have suggested several solutions below, but to no avail. i posted the data I am working with below the code.

it keeps saying I need to add more details, but this is it. Just need some help figuring out how to write json to two columns in a csv...

Hello? Can anyone please help me?

```
replies_final,original_final = [],[]

  for i in data['items']:
    original = i['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']
    original_final.append(original)
    if 'replies' in i: 
      x = i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal']
      replies_final.append(x)
 

    with open('test.csv',"a+", newline='',encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for item in original_final,replies_final:
            writer.writerows([item])
            writer.writerows([item])

 csv_file.close()
```

'''

```
      {
        "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
        "etag": "xJ-LhVfidkBCo_uBKu4E4Cv-YOQ",
        "id": "UgxE675r5LTCH_rERuF4AaABAg",
        "snippet": {
            "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
            "topLevelComment": {
                "kind": "youtube#comment",
                "etag": "rA2y-ABxa9twhiI52jjFqt_QNkg",
                "id": "UgxE675r5LTCH_rERuF4AaABAg",
                "snippet": {
                    "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                    "textDisplay": "I don\u2019t know if I believe this guy, my first doubt is why would the us government hire someone from the street to work on a top secret operation. If this was all true, I would imagine they would hand pick the best of the best from within their ranks, cia, nasa, government contractors to work on these secret projects, not just anyone.",
                    "textOriginal": "I don\u2019t know if I believe this guy, my first doubt is why would the us government hire someone from the street to work on a top secret operation. If this was all true, I would imagine they would hand pick the best of the best from within their ranks, cia, nasa, government contractors to work on these secret projects, not just anyone.",
                    "authorDisplayName": "Marcos Jimenez",
                    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzupYBdThhYUn47JHZdepkA4W_BtrA3skbUPA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrOPNqOqWm9IdO7dyMfHclQ",
                    "authorChannelId": {
                        "value": "UCrOPNqOqWm9IdO7dyMfHclQ"
                    },
                    "canRate": true,
                    "viewerRating": "none",
                    "likeCount": 0,
                    "publishedAt": "2020-07-31T23:13:07Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T23:13:07Z"
                }
            },
            "canReply": true,
            "totalReplyCount": 0,
            "isPublic": true
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
        "etag": "r4rF6BKHllB9T_lR4wsw5pXVNbA",
        "id": "UgwuobWtuMcOR8pIh014AaABAg",
        "snippet": {
            "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
            "topLevelComment": {
                "kind": "youtube#comment",
                "etag": "tikGuEG44O99xlCaX05RlAZIPww",
                "id": "UgwuobWtuMcOR8pIh014AaABAg",
                "snippet": {
                    "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                    "textDisplay": "Why is Jeremy Corbell even on this podcast",
                    "textOriginal": "Why is Jeremy Corbell even on this podcast",
                    "authorDisplayName": "sg",
                    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyuTS69KYuYl_XBQMdzevIJs48MG6suPK26MQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXcKVpS47zeQ9SBaFBQuOmw",
                    "authorChannelId": {
                        "value": "UCXcKVpS47zeQ9SBaFBQuOmw"
                    },
                    "canRate": true,
                    "viewerRating": "none",
                    "likeCount": 0,
                    "publishedAt": "2020-07-31T23:05:50Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T23:05:50Z"
                }
            },
            "canReply": true,
            "totalReplyCount": 0,
            "isPublic": true
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
        "etag": "8XvNjKtJZwweAoUvikN7bZeVPmU",
        "id": "UgyylyZswPsBV55zNYl4AaABAg",
        "snippet": {
            "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
            "topLevelComment": {
                "kind": "youtube#comment",
                "etag": "LIG1LVwaN7Q1604ahnCjvZaRGj8",
                "id": "UgyylyZswPsBV55zNYl4AaABAg",
                "snippet": {
                    "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                    "textDisplay": "The four world class body language experts on the Behavior Panel did an excellent job dissecting and revealing Lazar\u2019s fraud here on YouTube. Now this has become a major embarrassment for both Joe and George Knapp. It has made Joe look extremely foolish and gullible but even worse, it implicates Knapp in the fraud and discredits him as well. So it was not surprising that another podcast was hastily arranged with Knapp and Corbell clutching at straws trying to convince everyone that Lazar is not what the top body language experts say he is \u2013 a bare faced liar who never worked on an alien spaceship.",
                    "textOriginal": "The four world class body language experts on the Behavior Panel did an excellent job dissecting and revealing Lazar\u2019s fraud here on YouTube. Now this has become a major embarrassment for both Joe and George Knapp. It has made Joe look extremely foolish and gullible but even worse, it implicates Knapp in the fraud and discredits him as well. So it was not surprising that another podcast was hastily arranged with Knapp and Corbell clutching at straws trying to convince everyone that Lazar is not what the top body language experts say he is \u2013 a bare faced liar who never worked on an alien spaceship.",
                    "authorDisplayName": "It's Just What THEY Told Me, Pinky Swear.",
                    "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxMDcotXrLUQ7BQgdwZYlOoC683YKpz-rv9IzDZ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                    "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMxgt6CqOSwpX8NSlAk3AVg",
                    "authorChannelId": {
                        "value": "UCMxgt6CqOSwpX8NSlAk3AVg"
                    },
                    "canRate": true,
                    "viewerRating": "none",
                    "likeCount": 0,
                    "publishedAt": "2020-07-31T22:11:30Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-07-31T22:11:30Z"
                }
            },
            "canReply": true,
            "totalReplyCount": 2,
            "isPublic": true
        },
        "replies": {
            "comments": [
                {
                    "kind": "youtube#comment",
                    "etag": "_dC_TeoB2nlNsdwqrr4NlUtZrZc",
                    "id": "UgyylyZswPsBV55zNYl4AaABAg.9Bn9sJEV9_f9BoZFUkY59L",
                    "snippet": {
                        "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                        "textDisplay": "@MiniBull1903 \nHello MiniBull,\r\nI do not have enough interest in the story to be biased but I am very interested in the way humans think and especially in the type of content that triggers an emotional response from them. It will be apparent to others reading this exchange that a lot of what you say in your comment also applies to yourself. I have communicated with you extensively over the last year and you are not so different from Rombert, you both exhibit an above average intelligence and a steely determination. I also think you know that I am not a troll. That is not the main difference between us however, the main difference being something that separates me from all of you and I think that you might be starting to realize what that is now. You wrote: [Who\u2019s right, nobody knows.] Are you sure about that? It would be extremely arrogant to hold such a view without the kind of access that would unequivocally answer the question. There are only TWO possible avenues that would provide the means \u2013 the highest security clearance being but one of them.",
                        "textOriginal": "@MiniBull1903 \nHello MiniBull,\r\nI do not have enough interest in the story to be biased but I am very interested in the way humans think and especially in the type of content that triggers an emotional response from them. It will be apparent to others reading this exchange that a lot of what you say in your comment also applies to yourself. I have communicated with you extensively over the last year and you are not so different from Rombert, you both exhibit an above average intelligence and a steely determination. I also think you know that I am not a troll. That is not the main difference between us however, the main difference being something that separates me from all of you and I think that you might be starting to realize what that is now. You wrote: [Who\u2019s right, nobody knows.] Are you sure about that? It would be extremely arrogant to hold such a view without the kind of access that would unequivocally answer the question. There are only TWO possible avenues that would provide the means \u2013 the highest security clearance being but one of them.",
                        "parentId": "UgyylyZswPsBV55zNYl4AaABAg",
                        "authorDisplayName": "[Visitor by Proxy]",
                        "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxR1kpRpG9ePyhUA3YQofnPd5gotjhcbaz6bpiw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                        "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMmdJDTTFYr1uVNHfTYkCqA",
                        "authorChannelId": {
                            "value": "UCMmdJDTTFYr1uVNHfTYkCqA"
                        },
                        "canRate": true,
                        "viewerRating": "none",
                        "likeCount": 0,
                        "publishedAt": "2020-08-01T11:12:30Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-08-01T11:12:30Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "kind": "youtube#comment",
                    "etag": "I0sHtZRPYeiPAi1-fQQMk9k0oR0",
                    "id": "UgyylyZswPsBV55zNYl4AaABAg.9Bn9sJEV9_f9Bo9dYkK3P7",
                    "snippet": {
                        "videoId": "BEWz4SXfyCQ",
                        "textDisplay": "It's Just What THEY Told Me, Pinky Swear. - 12 million views, hardly an embarrassment. You are aware there are other \u2018Body Language experts\u2019 who have no doubt Bob is being truthful? You probably ignore those guys. Bob also passed Polygraph Tests - does this prove he\u2019s truthful, no. Would the trolls be all over it if he had failed said tests - 100% definitely.  Who\u2019s right, nobody knows. \nHere\u2019s a fact - if Bob\u2019s story had been proved to be BS beyond doubt, his story would\u2019ve vanished years ago. It evidently triggers the trolls & debunkers that the story is still prevalent today, probably even more so. You do get kudos for your clearly biased & relentless opinion.",
                        "textOriginal": "It's Just What THEY Told Me, Pinky Swear. - 12 million views, hardly an embarrassment. You are aware there are other \u2018Body Language experts\u2019 who have no doubt Bob is being truthful? You probably ignore those guys. Bob also passed Polygraph Tests - does this prove he\u2019s truthful, no. Would the trolls be all over it if he had failed said tests - 100% definitely.  Who\u2019s right, nobody knows. \nHere\u2019s a fact - if Bob\u2019s story had been proved to be BS beyond doubt, his story would\u2019ve vanished years ago. It evidently triggers the trolls & debunkers that the story is still prevalent today, probably even more so. You do get kudos for your clearly biased & relentless opinion.",
                        "parentId": "UgyylyZswPsBV55zNYl4AaABAg",
                        "authorDisplayName": "MiniBull1903",
                        "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyACocNK2JENn5jN702WVibSX8HAf3YrhmjBJTF=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
                        "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ6mfaV1y3DO1aor1itcIng",
                        "authorChannelId": {
                            "value": "UCZ6mfaV1y3DO1aor1itcIng"
                        },
                        "canRate": true,
                        "viewerRating": "none",
                        "likeCount": 0,
                        "publishedAt": "2020-08-01T07:28:44Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-08-01T07:39:55Z"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Your "if 'replies' in i:" only fires when the for loop is done completely and only checks on the last "i". Is that on purpose?

Comment: @DjerroNeth why is that the case? Thanks for the info, just learning. And no I don't intend on that.

Comment: because your if statement is outside the for loop

Comment: oh ok, that was actually just a mistake in copying the code over. I have that right in my ide. ill edit.

Comment: Because the indentation of the if statement is the same as your for loop, so it falls out of your for loop.

Comment: @DjerroNeth see above, that was a mistake in copying it over. it is corrected now. anything else that is standing out?

Comment: Can you make a quick sample output of what you expect?

Comment: just two columns to print out a list on each row by row

Comment: In your last for loop, item is actually  list of the two columns in that row. Wat happens if you just do `writer.writerows(item)`? I think that may write both of those as two rows, instead of writing both as four rows.

Comment: @wamster but with that he would have multiple columns and two rows

Comment: So I think the reason is that your `item` variable in the last for loop is not what you expect it to be. You can try `print(item)` on the first line inside that loop to explore what it is and that will tell you what is wrong. I think I know the problem, but if you do that suggestion it will help you get better at solving these things in thought manner instead of getting the answere once here. But if you get stuck I can help

Comment: @wamster print(item) is a list that I would expect

Comment: @LearningNoob  no, that would produce a single column, because on the first iteration, `item` is entirety of `original_final`, and then next item its entirety of `replies_final`. If you have a single list, `writer.writerows(['a', 'b', 'c'])` then that writes all that as a column, but if you have a list of lists, e.g. `writer.writerows([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']])` then each list is a row

Comment: @wamster part of the confusion, is that when I only try to iterate/write one of the lists to a csv, it works fine with a nested list.  for i in testing:
                                                            writer.writerows([[i]])

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
with open('test.csv', "a+", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(zip(original_final,replies_final))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various things you need to consider for instance if your item contains more than one reply you can store them all into a temporary array that you can later append to your `replies_final` object if it doesn't contain any replies it will remain empty and you still have fill your replies_final array with a 1:1 relationship with everyitem even if is empty

```py
  for i in data['items']:
    original = i['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']
    original_final.append(original)
    item_replies = []
    if 'replies' in i: 
        # Here you can iterate over the replies and add them to a temp array
        for reply in i['replies']:
            x = i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal']
            item_replies.append(x)
    replies_final.append(item_replies)
```

Then you can use the zip function that gets both arrays and turns them into a single object that you can iterate through and this is good because you already know that for every item you already have a list of comments even if it is empty the information will now mix. Then you are calling the wrong function instead of using `writerows()` you have to use `writerow()` to insert one at a time

````py
with open('test.csv',"a+", newline='',encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for i in zip(arr,arr2):
        (item, replies) = i
        writer.writerow([item, replies]))

 csv_file.close(
```
````

Answer (score 0):

My experiment in how this `csv.writer()` object works is that

`writer.writerow([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']])` produces the CSV file:

```
a, b, c
d, e, f
```

When you have `for item in original_final, replies_final` then on first iteration, `items` is a list equal to `original_final` and on second iteraton it is `replies_final` and so it produces a column containing `original_final` and then `replies_final`

What you want to have is on first iteration, item has two elements:

`[original_final[0], replies_final[0]]`

On second iteration, it should be
`[original_final[1], replies_final[1]]`

And so forth

To do that you can use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) function as follows

`for item in zip(original_final, replies_final):`

Now, Your next problem is that `original_final` and `replies_final` need to be the same length otherwise the `zip` function will clip the result based on the shortest of the two

So what you can do there is modify your `if` statement like this

```
if 'replies' in i: 
  x = i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal']
  replies_final.append(x)
else:
  replies_final.append('')
```

I think that should work

Also, with the `with` statement, you don't need to do `csv_file.close()`. You can just take that out

So here's the final code block

```
replies_final,original_final = [],[]

for i in data['items']:
    original = i['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']
    original_final.append(original)
    if 'replies' in i: 
       x = i['replies']['comments'][0]['snippet']['textOriginal']
       replies_final.append(x)
    else:
       replies_final.append('')


    with open('test.csv',"a+", newline='',encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for item in zip(original_final,replies_final):
            writer.writerows([item])
```

Let me know if that doesn't work

Arts, crafts and sciences uplift the world of being and are conducive to its exaltation ~Baha'u'llah

EDIT: Since its not working for you, what does this minimal example give you?

```
import csv

f=open('test.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8')

la=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lb=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

writer=csv.writer(f)

for item in zip(la, lb):
    writer.writerows([item])

f.close()
```

Comment: unfortunately no, that doesn't work. still in one column.

Comment: weird....you are on python3 correct? and in each iteration `item` is a list of strings, correct? its not nested with lists?

Comment: can you display the first three elements in those two lists, `original_final` and `replies_final`? also, you are doing `writer.writerows([item])` and not `writer.writerows(item)` correct?

Comment: correct it is a list of strings and yes I’m doing the right writerows.

Comment: anymore ideas? I am completely stumped

Comment: Check my answere, I've added a minimal example at the end

Comment: a,A
b,B
c,C
d,D   (can't format this right, but it is in two columns)

Comment: I can see how adapting this to my situation should work, but it simply isn't. I feel like im in the twilight zone :/  Does it make anymore sense to look at the json data I am working with? are you able to parse that into two columns?

Comment: I'm trying to load the json data into python but I'm getting errors....maybe only part of it got posted? Its seems like multiple separate bodies of data that aren't linked together by a parent key...not sure if I'm saying that right. or maybe I'm just loading it wrong. I did `data=f.read()` and then `obj=json.loads(data)`